# Stretchy header view for UICollectionview and minimize UIImageView while scrolling up

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to achieve a certain layout that looks like twitter and many other apps. Some people do it in UIVIewLayouts but I want to achieve it using this way (if possible ). As you see in the attached image. I have Header, and cells in the collectionview.

[image]

1. While scrolling up I want to minimize the imagview avatar inside the headerview. -> ( ViewForSupplementaryEelementHeader )
2. while scrolling down, I want to make the top UIImageview to be fixed to the top and stretchy

Thank you all in advance

*ps I am doing all of this in code nothing with storyboard and I dont want to use it at all.

Please advise me how to access these imageview while scrolling up and down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is the example you are looking for
https://github.com/sunlubo/StretchyHeaderView

This will add only tableview in storyboard...other all the work is done through coding